# feathersjs permissions - Roles

Tags: node.js, feathersjs

I am using feathersjs as a backend for an web app. I'm about to use the permissions to manage access to the database.

I have 3 roles: admin, organizer, user

I want to store the permissions for each role in a seperate table named "roles". And the user have a column with role and there I want to store the role ID.

Additionally each user only has right to edit his own row. so I need something like: 'users:update:1234' for each user.

How do I combine them. The documentation says the user table needs a column with "permissions" where I can store them. But I want to be more flexible.

Is there any good example for that? Internet is empty about it...

Greetings..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[feathers-permissions](https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-permissions) is the way to go for this. As [shown here](https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-permissions#permission-format) it should be possible to create the dynamic roles you want like this:

```
app.service('users').hooks({
  before: checkPermissions({
    roles(context) {
      return [ `users/${context.id}` ];
    }
  })
});
```

Now the user has to have the `users/123:update` permission. Instead of limiting the permissions by id however, to restrict requests to the current user, [feathers-authentication-hooks](https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-authentication-hooks) can be used.